# azcopy job not resuming and new transfer doesnt happen

Tags: azure, azcopy

I'm using Azopy version 10.1.2 azcopy_windows_amd64_10.1.2.

It was working fine and suddenly one day, the azcopy sync doesn't happen and it is just stuck.

```
azcopy jobs list

Existing Jobs
JobId: 960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492
Start Time: Thursday, 08-Aug-19 12:02:11 EDT
Command: sync https://desturlwithsas F:\testcom\prod\relevancy\dailydatafeed --recursive=true
```

Looks like there is a job that is stuck on Aug 08. When I try to resume

```
C:\Users\prosbcomrel>azcopy jobs resume 960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492 --source-sas="sas-token"

Job 960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\prosbcomrel/.azcopy/960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492.log

5 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 5 Total,


Job 960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0333
Total Number Of Transfers: 5
Number of Transfers Completed: 5
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 1937752970
Final Job Status: Completed
```

When I tried to do a new azcopy sync command, I get this error after an hour or so. (Adding more information)

```
C:\Users\test>azcopy sync "url" "C:\test" --recursive=true

Job 4cbe4169-4c5f-8e4e-5d75-1a439c951250 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\prosbcomrel/.azcopy/4cbe4169-4c5f-8e4e-5d75-1a439c951250.log

0 Files Scanned at Source, 0 Files Scanned at Destination
Cannot perform sync due to error: cannot list blobs. Failed with error -> github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go/pipeline.NewError, /home/vsts/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-pipeline-go@v0.2.1/pipeline/error.go:154
HTTP request failed

Get "blob url"timeout=901: dial tcp: lookup bxxxxa01.blob.core.windows.net: no such host
```

The same command works in another VM. I tried restarting the VM, tried to move the journal file in C:\Users\prosbcomrel.azcopy\plans\960809a2-b302-1b4e-76dc-aea3a5d1d492--00000 to another location. Nothing works. How can I cancel the job and get the new one working?

Thanks,

Comment: did maybe your SAS token expire?

Comment: I have encountered token expiration, it gives different error. Moreover, same command works on different VM

Comment: What do you mean `When I tried to do a new azcopy sync command, it does nothing.`? Is there any output or error message?

Comment: Edited to show error message

Comment: This looks like an internet connectivity issue. Just found out :) somehow network connectivity was lost.

Answer (score 0):

This was because of internet connection issue. Some enforced DNS policy messed up network connectivity and it worked after fixing it.